# Prevent Google Cardboard Pairing / Startup Screen on iOS

Tags: ios, google-cardboard

When my google cardboard app starts up for the first time, it launches a Google page that says "Google Cardboard. Let's get you set up. Pair your phone with your viewer for the best experience."

I'd like to control this experience to show my own initial screen before the google cardboard sdk launches. One reason for this is that I want people without cardboard to be able to immediately start experiencing the app in non-cardboard mode without having to go through the pairing process.

I know I can launch the pairing / viewer profile selector later on with the cardboard.ShowSettingsDialog().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this with the current version of the SDK is to have a starter scene without a Cardboard component in it.  It will not be in VR, and it won't trigger onboarding.

[edit] The function OnFocus() in CardboardiOSDevice.cs is where it decides to launch the onboarding dialog. You can suppress that by editing this function. But you may want to continue using the onboarding dialog for first time users, rather than the settings dialog, because of it walks them through the scanning process.

Comment: I suspect loading the full scene would also trigger the pop up. There's got to be a way to preset the profile since it doesn't do this on the 2nd run of the app.

Comment: The function OnFocus() in CardboardiOSDevice.cs is where it decides to launch the onboarding dialog.  You can suppress that by editing this function.  But you may want to use continue using the onboarding dialog for first time users, rather than the settings dialog, because of it walks them through the scanning process.

Comment: that's it, if you make it an answer I'll select it. Thank you!

Comment: OK, I added it in the answer above (not sure if I can post more than one answer).