# Remove Google Cardboard pairing message on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I've got an app developed and I need to get rid of the Google Cardboard pairing message that appears on iOS on first run - previous posts on here have suggested disabling //device.ShowSettingsDialog(); - this didn't work.

Another post suggested editing OnFocus() in CardboardiOSDevice.cs ([Prevent Google Cardboard Pairing / Startup Screen on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341896/prevent-google-cardboard-pairing-startup-screen-on-ios)) - but it wasn't explained how to achieve this?

Comment: All you have to do is to comment out the code in the `OnFocus()` function. I think that post is old and  Google Cardboard changed over time. Provide a link to the current version you are using and I will see if there is another way to do this

Comment: Ok. Check my answer. Not sure if that will work but give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Assets/Cardboard/Scripts/VRDevices**, open  `CardboardiOSDevice`.cs.

Look for this function:

```
  public override void OnFocus(bool focus) {
    if (focus && (debugOnboarding || !isOnboardingDone())) {
      debugOnboarding = false;
      launchOnboardingDialog();
    }
  }
```

then comment out everything inside it.

```
 public override void OnFocus(bool focus) {
    /*if (focus && (debugOnboarding || !isOnboardingDone())) {
      debugOnboarding = false;
      launchOnboardingDialog();
    }*/
  }
```

Comment: Tried this and I'm still getting the pairing message I'm afraid

Comment: @alib0ng0 Sorry for the late reply. I finally got time to run this. I did run it on iPhone 5s and my solution is working after I commented the code in the `OnFocus` function. Also comment the `ShowSettingsDialog` function and the code inside it. The project you sent me already had the `ShowSettingsDialog` function commented out. All you have to do is to comment out the code in the  `OnFocus` function like I said in my answer. Let me know if you need the fixed project. I will send it back to you.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I really want to know why it didn't work for you for the first time....